# Chef - using overriden attributes inside recipes applied inside a machine resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-zero, chef-provisioning

I have a recipe for provisioning an ec2 instance that I'm trying to apply an environment to, which I run as:

```
chef-client -z -o 'myapp::dev_create'
```

**The default.rb attributes file is defined as:**

```
default['myapp_provisioner'].tap do |myapp_provisioner|
  myapp_provisioner['node_name'] = 'test'
end
```

**The myapp::dev_create recipe is defined as:**

```
require 'chef/provisioning'
Chef::Config.chef_provisioning({
  :machine_max_wait_time => 240
})

# Override environment specific configs
node.override['myapp_provisioner']['node_name'] = 'RULZ_DEV'

include_recipe 'myapp_provisioner::ec2_instance' # sets machine_options

# The line below prints "RULZ_DEV" 
# as it is overridden above
puts node['myapp_provisioner']['node_name'] 

machine node['myapp_provisioner']['node_name'] do
  chef_environment 'DEV'
  admin true # run as sudo
  recipe 'myapp::copy_tls_certs'
  role 'reverse_proxy'
  role 'app_server'
end
```

**The Recipe myapp::copy_tls_certs is defined as:**

```
node_name = node['myapp_provisioner']['node_name']

# The line below prints the value from default attributes "test"
puts "cert path ---------------> #{node_name}"
```

**Updated**

I had previously titled the question as *`Chef Environment not overriding recipe called inside a machine resource`*, but I have come to realize that the issue is not related to Environments, but is only about attributes overriding and using those attributes inside a machine resource. It feels like I'm missing something quite fundamental here, any ideas?

Comment: Unclear if this is a redaction failure but you're straight up using a different attribute in the `copy_tls_certs` recipe. This is why you shouldn't redact things unless you're going to do it carefully :P

Comment: @coderanger, Thansk for getting back, I don't follow what you mean about redacting things, I wasn't intentionally trying to redact anything (I guess depends on what you mean by redact). Anyway, I have updated the question after I realized the problem is not about applying environments, but just about using overridden attributes within a machine resource's runlist

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. Your EC2 machine has no idea about `node['myapp_provisioner']['node_name']` being overridden in `myapp::dev_create` recipe, because this recipe is not in its run list.

What chef-client does on that machine is:

1. Expand the run list.

   It gets the `myapp::copy_tls_certs` recipe and those others that make the `reverse_proxy` and `app_server` roles. (but they are not important now)
2. It reads *all* the attribute files of the cookbooks in the expanded run list.

   So it reads `myapp/attributes/default.rb` and gets the default value for the `node['myapp_provisioner']['node_name'] = 'test'`
3. It goes through the recipes in run list and creates a collection of resources or executes ruby code, if it's not a resource.

   In your case it runs `myapp::copy_tls_certs` and prints the `test`, because that's what it is :)

If you want your overridden attribute to be in the provisioned EC2 machine, you have to move the override line to some other recipe, which you can then include into `machine` resource `recipe` attribute. Or may be (I don't know, because I have never seen this `machine` resource before) this `machine` resource has also `attribute` property, so you can pass the override attribute through it.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I had the same idea after seeing the attribute on machine, I ended up passing the override attributes to the machine's attributes property which creates new normal attributes with those override values, whether that's the correct way or not, I know not

Answer (score 0):

For the next person that will go through a similar problem, this is what I ended up with.

**The myapp::create recipe is defined as:**

```
require 'chef/provisioning'

# Override attributes [I put these in an Environment file, much cleaner]
node.override['myapp_provisioner']['node_name'] = 'RULZ_DEV'

include_recipe 'myapp_provisioner::ec2_instance' # sets machine_options 

machine node['myapp_provisioner']['node_name'] do
  chef_environment 'DEV'
  admin true # run as sudo
  attributes node['myapp_provisioner'] # pulls all attributes
  role 'reverse_proxy'
  role 'app_server'
end
```

That pulls overriding attributes into newly created normal attributes during the chef-client run.
As indicated in the comment, I put these in an environment file to keep the recipe clean and I run that as:

```
chef-client -z -o 'brms::reate' -E DEV
```